# React - Context Provider - Calling Async Function Inside Consumer Returns Nothing After Promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to call an async function from the provider and then show content based on the response but nothing is returned. Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong?
Below is the code:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <UserConsumer>
        {
          ({getProfile}) => {
            getProfile.then(profile) => {
              return profile && (
                <h3>{profile.name}</h3>
              )
            }
          }
        }
      </UserConsumer>
    </>
  )
}
```

I can see getProfile returns a promise with profile data and even if I remove `profile &&` nothing shows. I have used other functions the same way. getProfile is the only async function and not sure why am I having this issue.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your `UserConsumer`'s rendering logic is something like this:

```
<div>{props.children({getProfile})}</div>
```

Since you are not returning anything in this function:

```
     ({getProfile}) => {
        getProfile.then(profile) => {
          return profile && ( // this is return value of then callback, not props.children
            <h3>{profile.name}</h3>
          )
        }
      }
```

Everytime React renders `UserConsumer`, the final JSX to be rendered is this:

```
    <div>{undefined}</div>
```

The main problem of your code, You are not supposed to do asynchronous operations in return sections of React Components.

If you need to render some UI based on server side data (like profile data), you need to fetch data in `useEffect`, then put the received data in some `state`, and use the `state` in return of the component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looked weird to me too but I have not used React context much so did not think much that in that pattern whole async function does not making sense. 
I do understand what you are saying. How can I use the aync function from the in a useEffect? Can you point me to a resource or describe how I could do that?

Comment: @sayayin You are welcome. there are plenty of resources, read this one as an example https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/,

Comment: Thanks Erfan, guess I know how to use useEffect with an async function. I meant how can I call that function from the provider. Main confusion was how would I use the <UserConsumer> to get the function. I  believe I can use useContext hook to get the function and call that in useEffect. Right?